# 3 <div> => middle <div> overlaps upper and lower <div>

Tags: html, css

How can I overlap 3 `<div>` so that the middle `<div>` is on top of the other two.

I've tried:

```
#middle { 
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
}
```

But that only has the effect of overlapping the upper but not the lower `<div>`...[image: 3 overlapping divs]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use css `position`
check the working code @[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/58j2p/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Use position:absolute to take the middle div out of the layout.

```
<div id="upper">Upper content</div>
<div id="middle">Middle content</div>
<div id="lower">Lower Content</div>

div { width:180px;height:100px;border:3px solid #000; }
#upper { border-color:#FF0; }
#middle { position:absolute;top:100px;border-color:F00; }
#lower { margin-top:80px;border-color:#0F0 }
```