# How to position content above the header and footer

Tags: html, css, layout, positioning

The positioning I want to acheive:
[image]

Now I have the following:
[image]

The properties are following:

```
.header, .footer {
    background: #666;
    height: 100px;
}

.content {
    background: #ccc;
    margin: -25px auto;
    min-height: 500px;
    width: 960px;
}
```

So the problem that the content lays below the footer and I don't know how to fix it. z-index doesn't work.

My HTML:

```
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
.header, .footer {
    background: #666;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.content {
    background: #ccc;
    margin: -25px auto;
    min-height: 500px;
    width: 960px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This example is similar.

[3 <div> => middle <div> overlaps upper and lower <div>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7495058/3-div-middle-div-overlaps-upper-and-lower-div)